# Webpack & SCSS: Attempted import error: '' is not exported from '' (imported as '')

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I have scss variables exported from a scss module and then imported into a React component but receive this error when trying to build my application with webpack:

Attempted import error: 'groupedOptionsBottomBorderColor' is not exported from 'scss/base/_export.module.scss' (imported as 'groupedOptionsBottomBorderColor').

Here is the relevant code:

```
@import 'index';
/* stylelint-disable property-no-unknown*/
:export {
  ...
  groupedOptionsBottomBorderColor: $color-blue-900-20;
  ...
}
/* stylelint-enable property-no-unknown*/
```

```
import { groupedOptionsBottomBorderColor } from "scss/base/_export.module.scss";
```

I have tried importing that variable in a few other ways such as:

```
import * as styles from "scss/base/_export.module.scss";
const groupedOptionsBottomBorderColor = styles.groupedOptionsBottomBorderColor;

// or

import { groupedOptionsBottomBorderColor } from "../../../../scss/base/_export.module.scss";
```

Webpack config:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [stylesHandler, "style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
```

but I receive the same error each time.  I am not sure if there is another way this can be written that would prevent this error or if something has changed in one of the libraries that we are using.
The versions of each relevant library:

```
"webpack": "^5.89.0",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"sass": "^1.69.7",
```

and Node version 20.  Is this syntax wrong for importing scss variables into a React component?

Comment: I think there has been a breaking change at some point that broke the destructuring on import from styles. I searched but I can't pinpoint when and where is changed exactly. Try with: `import styles from "scss/base/_export.module.scss";`